# Can I force a user to upgrade my app?

Tags: iphone, app-store, upgrade

Can I force a user to upgrade my app? Does Apple recommend it?

Comment: You could have your app connect to a server that returns the latest app version and compares it to the one you're running, and handle that, but I doubt Apple will be fond of this.

Comment: users generally don't like this, even if you have the best of intentions. before considering if you *can*, consider if you *should*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just check the version number when the application starts and if needed, bail out with an error screen. I don’t think Apple explicitly prohibits this. (And I doubt they would find out during the review.) Of course it’s annoying from the user’s viewpoint, I would only write something like that if there was no other option.

Comment: Just post a simple file with the latest version number to your webserver and check it when the app starts, @DataGreed.

Comment: wellm that's not very automated. Btw, does this app behavior violate any Apple ToS?

Comment: there is a way, however - you can use app store api.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can force an upgrade to the user. You can call a webservice when your app start and check on your server if an update is available (you have to add an update when an  update available on app store). If an update is available then you can present a view that will have the update button. When pressed this button will redirect the user to the installed app store app and open the upgraded app in it. (you should return this url in your webservice). Let me know in comments if you need more explanations.

And I don't know apple recommend this way. But I have seen this in one or two apps.

Comment: Thank you Saurabh i know how to upgrade the application but i just want to know whether apple recommnds it if we make the user upgrade forcefully.

Comment: As zoul said I don't think apple will reject your app because of this. also as he said they will not found this in their review because your webservice will not return available update. I am also integrating this in my current app

Answer (score 0):

Extremely bad approach. My perfectly fine working app forces upgrade, which can not be supported due to obsolete iOS. I am not only forced, but moving away from the coupon app in determination to never use it web-based either.
Security issue, if that is the reason for upgrade, should be patched for existing iOS.